# Dates in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, sql-update

I am trying to use following queries but the browser says 
**Fatal error: Call to undefined function FROM_UNIXTIME()**

```
$query = "UPDATE table
             SET datetimefield = FROM_UNIXTIME($phpdate)
           WHERE...";
$query = "SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetimefield)
            FROM table 
           WHERE...";
```

I am following http://www.richardlord.net/blog/dates-in-php-and-mysql

Comment: you can try if  this works `SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()))) AS test`

Comment: are you sure your database supports that function? what flavor and version of SQL do you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use a database function on a PHP variable. Try this:

```
$query = "UPDATE table
             SET datetimefield = FROM_UNIXTIME(" . strtotime($phpdate) . ")
           WHERE...";
$query = "SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetimefield)
            FROM table 
           WHERE...";
```